# Strange darkened halo around white box shadow

Tags: css, stylus

I put a white box shadow around a button that sits absolutely in the corner of the parent div so that content around it is gently faded away as it gets closer to the button, however there's a strange black halo around the shadow. What's causing this and how can I get rid of it?

[image]

This is the code excerpt. I'm using stylus as my preprocessor with nib.

```
.card-link {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: $card-padding.medium;
    right: $card-padding.medium;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 20px white;
}

<div class="c-card">
    <div class="c-card-container">
        <div class="face front " style="background-image: url({{ file_url(paragraph.field_card_image.entity.uri.value) }})">
            <span class="card-image icon-{{paragraph.field_card_image_is_icon.value}}">
            {% if paragraph.field_card_image is empty %}
                <div class="card-title">{{paragraph.field_card_title.value}}</div>
                <div class="card-content">{{content.field_card_text}}</div>
                <div class="card-link">{{content.field_card_link}}</div>
            {% endif %}
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="face back">
        {% if paragraph.field_card_image is not empty %}

            <div class="card-title">
            {% if paragraph.field_card_title is not empty %}
                {{paragraph.field_card_title.value}}
            {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">{{content.field_card_text}}</div>
            <div class="card-link">{{content.field_card_link}}</div>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

Viewing the page in incognito seems to remove the halo which suggests that the admin bar from the CMS (Drupal) has some CSS that's influencing the rendering of box-shadow. There isn't another box-shadow that's overriding the style as my box shadow has top priority.

Comment: Could you post the html as well? I see you have box-shadow listed twice. Is that correct?

Comment: That was just me troubleshooting. That wasn't there prior.

Comment: This sounds like you got another style for links or buttons that is overwriting this style. You need to turn of those properties in this one as well. You can check for example in Chrome with inspect Element and see on the right sight the properties of CSS those are set

Comment: @StuiterSlurf Already did, that's not it.

Comment: Are you sure there's not another box-shadow in your code somewhere overriding this style? That looks like a box-shadow.

Comment: What is the point of this, anyways? You want a box-shadow around a link that allows words to cross into it? Weird.

Comment: @Dream_Cap That's because it is a box shadow. It's a white box-shadow but for some reason there is a darkened halo around it, which suggests that the colour it's fading out to is not white but actually a pure transparent black.

Comment: @PHPglue Read the question.

Comment: Could you post the HTML associated with this?

Comment: @DollarChills Viewing the page in incognito seems to remove the halo which suggests that the admin bar from the CMS (Drupal) has some CSS that's influencing the rendering of box-shadow.

Comment: Maybe throw a Drupal tag on this as well. Without seeing some source code, it's hard to tell where the issue is.

Comment: @DollarChills I've added the card HTML, although adding box shadows on the highest div element seems to yield the same effect.

Comment: @Semirix can you show what it shows then? I can't see what's wrong with this CSS when I try it out stand alone.